# Noob regex poser (match MAY contain and MUST have)

Tags: regex

Probably really simple for you Regex masters :) I'm a noob at regex, just having picked up some PHP, but wanting to learn (once this project is complete, I'll knuckle down and crack regular expressions).
I'd like to understand how to compose a regex that may contain some data, but must contain other.

My example being, the match MAY begin with numbers but doesn't have to, however if it does, I need the number and the following 2 words. If it doesn't begin with a number, just the first 2 words. The data will be at the beginning of the string.

The following would match:

- 123 Fore Street, Fiveways (123 Fore Street returned(no comma))
- Our House Village (Our House returned)
- 7 Eightnine (7 Eightnine returned)

Thanks

Comment: 7 Eightnine doesnt return 2 words as u claimed..it returns a digit and a word

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It, `My example being, the match MAY begin with numbers but doesn't have to, however if it does, I need the number and the following 2 words.` [7 Eightnine] In this case the number `7` and `Eightnine` will be returned because there's only one word available. I don't see any out of the odd imo ...

Comment: For the record, noone cares what level you are exactly at, especially not if you call youself a noob, formulate questions only with relevant information. I  edited the question but the que is full >.<. Just so people don't think this is in any way a good question, the language is horrible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this should work:

`^((?:\d+\s)?\w+(?:\s\w+)?)`

You can test it out somewhere like http://rubular.com/ before coding it, it's usually easier.

What it means:

^ -> beginning of the line

`(?:\d+\s)?` -> a non capturing group, (marked by ?:), consisting of several digits and a space, since we follow it by `?`, it's optional.

`\w+(?:\s\w+)?` -> several alphanumeric characters (look up what \w means), followed by, optionally, a space and another "word", again in a non capturing group.

The whole thing is encapsulated in a capturing group, so group 1 will contain your match.

Comment: Works great in Rubular and I have learnt more about grouping thanks to your explanations, however I'm missing something in my code. I have `$title = preg_match('#^((?:\d+\s)?\w+(?:\s\w+)?)#', '$1', $address);`, where `$address` equals the result of an xpath query. If I `echo $address`, I see what should contain a match, but if I `echo $title` it is empty. What am I missing?

Comment: Figured it out, my preg_match should have been `preg_match('#^((?:\d+\s)?\w+(?:\s\w+)?)#', $address, $title);`. Thanks for the regex

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex with multiline option

```
^(\d+(\s*\b[a-zA-Z]+\b){1,2}|(\s*\b[a-zA-Z]+\b){1,2})
```

`Group1` contains your required data

`\d+` means match digit i.e `\d` 1 to many times`+`

`\s*` means match space i.e `\s` 0 to many times`*`

`(\s*\b[a-zA-Z]+\b){1,2}` matches 1 to 2 words..